# Cat file to terminal at particular speed of lines per second

Tags: command-line, unix, speed, scrolling, cat

I'm lazy and I could write a script to do this, but I'm even too lazy to think of how to do it.

I often do things like :

```
cris$ python runexperiment.py > output.txt
cris$ cat output.txt
```

Sometimes when looking at the long output of an experiment I like to let the page just scroll and watch the successive patterns form and disperse. But using cat on a file with 1 million lines finishes in maybe 5 seconds. This is too quick even for me.

Is there any way that I can slow down the speed of viewing the file, something like a 'scroll utility'? I want fast, but not 200k lines a second (all of which presumably the display would never even register anyway).

Something like

```
cris$ scroll -lps=300 output.txt
```

And then sitting back and watching 300 lines per second roll past would be ideal, I imagine.

Comment: Try something like `cat FILENAME | pv -l -L 900 -q`. The limit is in bytes per second, not lines per second, so I'm making this a comment not an answer.

Comment: Ok well that is a cool utility, and that works in part. But yes, it is a little choppy since it goes after bps not lps.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'd upvote it if it was an answer. worked best for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### Short and *readable*:

```
perl -pe "system 'sleep .003'" log.txt
```

I post this solutions because they are small and readable, as comments of [DMas's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1282475) seem promote this kind of solution!

But I hate this because: For this run, perl will *fork* to `/bin/sleep` 300x / seconds!

This is a big ressource consumer! Also a wrong *good solutions*!!

#### Using *builtin* sleep in [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

Unfortunely, builtin `sleep` is limited to integers. So we have to use `select` instead:

```
perl -e 'print && select undef,undef,undef,.00333 while <>;'
```

Under perl, `print while <>` could be replaced by the `-p` switch:

```
perl -pe 'select undef,undef,undef,.00333'
```

Let's try:

```
time /bin/ls -l /usr/bin | perl -pe 'select undef,undef,undef,.00333' | wc
   2667   24902  171131

real    0m9.173s
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.048s

bc -l < <(echo 2667/9.173)
290.74457647443584432573
```

Explanation:

- 300 lines / sec means 1 line by 0.0033333333 secs.
- `print` without argument prints `$_` which is *default input space*.
- called as `... | perl -e`, `... | perl -ne` or `... | perl -pe`, standard input would be automaticaly assigned to `*STDIN` which is *default file descriptor*, so `<>` would do the same as `<STDIN>` which will read from standard input until `$/` (*input record separator* which is by default a *newline*) will be reached. In English, by default `<>` will read *one* line from standard input and assign content to `$_` variable.
- `&&` is an *and* condition, but is used there as a *chain command separator* so after (successfully) print one line, doing next command.
- `select` is a *programmer's trick to not use `sleep`*. This command is designed to trap events on *file descriptors* (inputs and/or outputs, files, socket and/or net sockets). With this command, a program could *wait* for 3 kind of events, *feed ready to read*, *feed ready to write* and *some event happened on feed*. The fourth argument is a timeout in seconds, so syntax is `select <feeds where wait for input>, <feeds where having to write>, <feed where something could happen>, <timeout>`.

For more precision, you could use `Time::Hires` perl module:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes -pe 'BEGIN{$start=Time::HiRes::time;$sleepPerLine=1/300};select undef,undef,undef,($start + $sleepPerLine*$. - Time::HiRes::time)'
```

Note: `$.` is *current input line number*.

Better written as `cat >catLps.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw|time|;

my $start=time;
my $lps=300;

$lps=shift @ARGV if @ARGV && $ARGV[0]=~/^(\d+)$/;
my $sleepPerLine=1/$lps;

print &&
    select undef,undef,undef,($start + $sleepPerLine*$. - Time::HiRes::time)
    while <>
```

**Usage:**

> `catLps.pl [lps] [file] [file]...`
>
> First argument *`lps`* is optional line per seconds numeric argument (default: 300)
>
> Note: if filename is only numeric, you may have to specifiy them with path: `./3`.
>
> Like `cat` this could pass files given as argument and/or *standard input*

So we could:

```
TIMEFORMAT='%R' 
time seq 1 100 | ./catLps.pl 100 >/dev/null 
1.040

time seq 1 10000 | ./catLps.pl 10000 >/dev/null  
1.042
```

For fun:

```
export TIMEFORMAT='%R' ;clear ;time seq 1 $((LINES-2)) | ./catLps.pl $((LINES-2))
```

Comment: that looks like some serious voodoo you are doing there. that is so cool, i tried it and it works. i have no idea how you did that though. what the hell is perl select ? undef? i can look it up. amazing.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow Ok, I've added some explanation and a full script using `Time::HiRes` perl module for more accuracy

Comment: my god. That is an awesome answer. Thank you. I tried to upvote it a second time. I am learning something by reading your wonderful explanation.

Comment: You could upvote my comments too ;-)

Comment: @CrisStringfellow Answer edited: by the use of `-p` switch to perl command, the script was lightened!

Answer (score 12):

just use awk with sleep:

```
awk '{print $0; system("sleep .1");}' log.txt
```

Comment: This worked for me and for my situation was the best option rather than the script options above. Unsure why this answer is down-voted.

Comment: Unlike the perl solution it is quite readable.

Comment: @Gunslinger: Syntax `system(*sleep .1")` will generate 10 forks / secs! This could be written `perl -pe 'system "sleep .1"' log.txt`: Readable too, but  very expensive (not system friendly!)

Comment: I too prefer this readable answer. The only thing is it will fire the shell sleep command for every line it outputs. But being a perfect readable one liner I don't care.

Comment: If you do use this command (which works great, BTW!), have another shell open where you can _kill -9_ it to get it to stop...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using an interpreter you can use a tool specifically made.
It's likely installed on your distro or you can install it (apt-get install pv, etc..)

To display the file at 5 lines per second:

```
cat filename | pv --quiet --line-mode --rate-limit 5
```

To display the file at 100 bytes per second:

```
cat filename| pv --quiet  --rate-limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I found this would be a useful learning exercise to try in python, so I'll put up what i got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
from time import sleep

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Echo a file slowly')
parser.add_argument('-i',
                    '--input-file',
                    type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                    default='-')
parser.add_argument('-d',
                    '--delay-in-ms',
                    type=int,
                    default='100')
args = parser.parse_args()

for line in args.input_file:
    print(line.rstrip())
    sleep(args.delay_in_ms/1000.0)
```

It accepts input from stdin or as an argument (-i) and by default writes one line per 1/10th of a second, but that can be changed with another argument (-d).

Comment: Thanks. I was starting to develop something similar to this idea in Python when I happened upon this Q&Ad.  I note that Python also supports select https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html in a similar way to Perl as used in F. Hauri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `sleep` function supports floating point values, so here's an efficient and short solution based on @F.Hauri's answer:

```
ruby -pe 'sleep 0.00333' log.txt
```

or

```
ruby -pe 'sleep (1.0/300)' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to mention two great tools:

1. `tee`
2. `cstream`

`tee` is good for capturing stdout to file as well as stream it. i.e. we can rewrite:

```
$ python runexperiment.py > output.txt
$ cat output.txt
```

as

```
$ python runexperiment.py | tee output.txt
```

The advantage of the latter version is the `output.txt` is being built at the same time output is displayed on `stdout`. So, you don't have to wait till the end of the experment.

The other tool I mention, `cstream`, can be used to slow down output, e.g.

```
$ python runexperiment.py | cstream -t 700k | tee output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you like a really slow rate (e.g. slower than 1 line per second) and prefer more basic commands like (gnu) xargs and sleep, you can use the following:

```
cat filename | xargs -d\\n -n1 -I{} sh -c "echo {}; sleep <n>"
```

replace *<n>* with the proper value for your line rate. *-d\\n* is a gnu specific extension that delimits per '\n'